# 8085 Assembly emulator for Win7(64)

Tags: assembly

I am looking for a free 8085 Assembler that runs on Windows 7 - 64 bit. I downloaded a few off the some shareware sites but most of them don't seem to run at all on Win7-64 bit. I tried running one using a DOS Emulator, but that hung DOSBox itself.

Anyone knows a 8085 emulator which will run on Win7-64?
One where I can step through code & also show flags, registers etc would be great, but even one that can just assemble & run would be good enough.

UPDATE: Found one which runs fine on Win7-64 bit - http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnusim8085/

Comment: Assemblers don't emulate.  Emulators don't assemble.  What are you really looking for?

Comment: ... if there was ever an easy emulator to write, it should be an 8085 emulator.  A 256-way switch statement with a 65Kb unsigned-char array is the basic structure; fill in code for each opcode.  You should be able to build this yourself in an exhausting weekend.

Comment: I am looking for a program which runs on 64 bit Win7 & takes a 8085 assembly program as input & executes them in the way they would execute on a 8085 processor. Ergo it's both an assembler & an emulator. It assembles the assembly code & generates 8085 instructions. It then emulates an 8085 processor & runs the assembled code on the emulator. There are several such programs available which run on WinXP, but I am unable to get them to run properly on Win7 64 bit - Here is an example - http://www.b2ccode.com/projects/8085_sdk/8085_sdk.php

Comment: OK, you can bundle an emulator and an assembler into a IDE-like system.   If the ones you see run find under WinXP as 32 bit apps, why shouldn't they run fine under X64 as 32 bit apps?  (one answer is, they aren't 32 bit apps. In that case, you're probably dead and you'll have to do as I suggested and build your own).  If you don't want to put a bunch of energy here, I'd build the emulator separate from the assembler.  Usually pretty doesn't matter as much as useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ones that didn't work on 7, but supposedly work on XP (but not DOS), why don't you just install XP mode on your Windows 7?  I've had really good success using the Windows 7 XP mode.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks. I didn't know something like that existed.